File listing all the packages installed with Nix package manager
I just installed nix package manager on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I was wondered if there exist a file which lists all the packages installed with nix (in order for example to list all the packages installed on one machine to automate the installation on a newer machine)

I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Deleted my reply....

If you used nix-env for installing the packages, nix-env -q will list their names.
The flake-based nix profile provides nix profile list.
